# Nested ng-repeat with constrained data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a nested ng-repeat as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="item_l in list1">
    <div ng-repeat="item_f in list2">
        {{item_f}} {{item_l}}
    </div>
</div>
```

It gives me about 20 results, but i want only 5 of them. How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use  [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

```
<div ng-repeat="item_l in list1">
    <div ng-repeat="item_f in list2 | limitTo : 5">
        {{item_f}} {{item_l}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[`DEMO APP`](https://jsfiddle.net/sk7znaL2/)